# Set the Image from String in ImageResource

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am passing `url` from next First Activity to second Activity and load in `Imageview` with Below Code

```html
ImageView cover_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_image);


         Picasso.with(book_details.this).load(book_image_txt).placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.bshelf).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(cover_image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            ImageView cover_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_image);
               String book_image_txt = "";
               Intent intent = getIntent();

              book_image_txt = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_IMAGE);
                 Picasso.with(book_details.this).load(book_image_txt).into(cover_image);
        }
    });
```

which does load the image from url if online and if not from the cached image. Now I was looking to zoom in image when Clicked for which i use the library

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
```

Now Since I want to use String  book_image_txt to load image which when I used in below code with

```
 photoView.setImageResource(book_image_txt);
```

It throws error , I also used

```
photoView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(book_image_txt));
```

but when compiled and run and if I click on Image, loads the alertdialog box but it is empty and no image is loaded

Below is the code for Photoview.

```html
mIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
                PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nature);
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                mDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess `book_image_txt`is not a drawable resource file. It's a string ID which leads to a possible exception.

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: @Fabio no it doesnot give any error when compiled  ..just when I use  book_image_txt inside setImageResource, then it is highlighted in red color ..so I used photoView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(book_image_txt)); instead and after compiling and running ..when I click imageview..it launches the alertdialog box but there is no image and it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Picasso.with(getApplication()).load("<URL>").into(photoView);
```